# Unable to delete the ad unit in admob

Tags: android, admob

In admob my account is limited. so I decided to remove the ad units and create new ad units. problem is I am unable to delete the native add ad unit. I am getting this message "An error occurred while trying to remove the selected ad unit(s). Please try again later."

[image]

Comment: As the image says, have you tried again later?

Comment: many time in different browsers. no difference, the same message appears.